# GPO IE Favorites Adds Unwanted Folders

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I created a AD 2003 GPO to add a couple of the company's links to everyone's IE.  I have the following:

Checked: Place Favorites and Links at the Top of the List...
Unchecked: Everything else

Then:

```
Favorites
|-Company Link One
|-Company Link Two
Links
```

However, the GPO seems to add Favorites Bar, Microsoft Websites, MSN Websites, and Windows Live folders.  If they are deleted it seems to make them come back.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version Windows/IE?  Those seem like the default collection of Favorites.  Are they present in the Default User's profile 'Favorites' folder?

Comment: In my Case 7/XP, I *think* also 8/XP it is the same thing.  I don't see them in the Favorites folder for all users or the default user for me at least.

Comment: Do you use IEAK in your deployments or IE config?

Comment: jscott: Don't know what that it is so I don't think so.  This is one of the first real GPOs, current the AD set up and computer deployment is pretty pedestrian.

Comment: Check "%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\Signup\" and/or "%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\Custom\" for any .INS files. Either of these could contain the branding Favorites you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing with a default install of Windows 7 I was able to reproduce this issue.

The Default Favorites appear to part of a feature titled "Local Packs". You can either [disable the Local Pack](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;2007064&sd=rss&spid=14498) or [remove it from your WIM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799277%28WS.10%29.aspx).  A decent article describing Local Packs is available [here](http://www.withinwindows.com/2010/01/24/demystifying-windows-7-local-packs-and-the-mct-folders/).

The command `mctadmin.exe /r US`, as an Administrator, worked on my test install.

I was not able to reproduce the same issue under Windows XP SP3/IE8

Edit:

It's worth noting that this did not appear to remove the default MS Favorites folders. Removing the Local Pack allowed the user to delete the default folders and they did not reappear upon restart.  Should you want to purge the default folder for existing user profiles you may want to use a simple logon script.

```
IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Microsoft Websites" RMDIR /S Q "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Microsoft Websites"
IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\MSN Websites" RMDIR /S Q "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\MSN Websites"
```

Answer (score 1):

Search your registry for BrandIE4

If this exists then the key it is located in will also show you branding.cab etc

This is the autiomatically installed group of favourites for all new users on that pc.

Youll either need to get the IEAK out and get rid of them with a new installation or remove the registy key with a script pushed via GPO